# TapGesture on ExtendedWebView not working

Tags: xamarin.forms

i am setting tapgesture to my extendedweb view however the command doesnt get fired. This is my view model.

View model

```
public ICommand MakeLargerCommand { get; private set; }
```

Constructor VM

```
MakeLargerCommand = new Command(() => MakeWebViewLarge()) ;
```

My ExtendedWebView in Xaml

```
 <StackLayout  >
                                            <controls:ExtendedWebView

                                                BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource MainWrapperBackgroundColor}"
                                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                Opacity="1"
                                                Source="{Binding CZ}"
                                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                                                <controls:ExtendedWebView.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding MakeLargerCommand}"/>
                                                </controls:ExtendedWebView.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </controls:ExtendedWebView>

                                        </StackLayout>
```

Do you have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if anyone is dealing with the same issue, my extended view tap gesture was not working at all. I solved it by adding Boxview on top of it and added gesture on the boxview

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions to troubleshoot

1. Use `Tapped` event instead of command to check if it is able to be triggered.

   ```
   <controls:ExtendedWebView.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="tapEventInPage"/>                                                
    </controls:ExtendedWebView.GestureRecognizers>
   ```
2. If it triggers as expect , revert the code and check if you forgot to set `BindingContext` in Page constructor.

   ```
   public MainPage()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.BindingContext = new YourViewModel();
   }
   ```